# Convert NSNumber to NSString with NSNumberFormatter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnumberformatter

I am converting an `NSNumber` to an `NSString` assuming in this example that the selected key in `"theindex"` is `1000000`

```
NSNumber  *firstNumber = [tempDict objectForKey:@"theindex"];
NSString *convertNumber = [firstNumber stringValue];
```

Returning the `NSString` "1000000"

I would like the string's value to be "1,000,000".

I am not concerned with localization, but understand from other questions that `NSNumberFormatter` should be implemented. I am not sure how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is an example using a standard formatting style of NSNumberFormatter:

```
NSNumber *firstNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:123456789];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSString *convertNumber = [formatter stringForObjectValue:firstNumber];
NSLog(@"value : %@", convertNumber);
```

Other examples you can reference at:
http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/formatting-numbers-nsnumberformatter-examples.html

Answer (score 2):

```
 NSNumber  *firstNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1000000] ;
 NSNumberFormatter *format=[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
 [format setGroupingSize:3];
 [format setCurrencyGroupingSeparator:@","];
 [format setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
 NSString *convertNumber = [format stringFromNumber:firstNumber];
```